# ion-tab is above ion-content, ion-tabs is unter ion-content

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ionic-framework

i want to put an ion-tab-bar component on top of my ion-content component, but the ion-tab-bar will be placed above the ion-content component, creating a black bar. at the bottom i want to add an ion -tabs component here it is the same. how do i get the result i want?

[image]

page.html:

```
<ion-tab-bar slot="top">
</ion-tab-bar>

<ion-content id="mapId" style="height:100% ; width:100%">
</ion-content>
```

page.css:

```
ion-header{
  --ion-toolbar-background-color: transparent;
--ion-toolbar-text-color: white;
}

ion-tab-bar{
  //position: absolute;
  --border:none;
  --background: rgba(255,255,255,5);
  margin: 15px 15px 0px 15px;
  border-radius: 14px;
  box-shadow:
  0px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.04),
  0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
}
```

nav.html:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">

    <ion-tab-button tab="spots">
      <ion-icon name="map-outline"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="vending">
      <ion-icon src="assets/vending.svg"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="favoriten">
      <ion-icon name="bookmarks-outline"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="startseite">
      <ion-icon name="home-outline"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="me">
      <ion-icon name="person-outline"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>

  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

nav.css:

```
ion-tab-bar{
  //position: absolute;
  --border:none;
  --background: rgba(255,255,255,5);
  margin: 16px 20px;
  border-radius: 14px;
  box-shadow:
  0px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.04),
  0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);

}
```